# Custom language server: how to get the client to send *all* files to the server, not just those opened/edited by the user?

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm working on implementing a custom language server and a VSCode language extension. My starting point for the client side is [`lsp-sample`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-sample). My server implementation is entirely from scratch, in a different language (not JS).

Currently, I've successfully set up `textDocument/didOpen` and `textDocument/didChange` messages to be sent by the client and received by the server. **However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to synchronize *all* files in the VSCode workspace, not just those that the user has opened.** I can't find where this is supported in the [protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/). The only [text document synchronization capabilities](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#textDocument_synchronization) I see are for documents opening, closing, and edits. What about all the other documents in the workspace?

For example, in order to handle "goto definition" requests, the server needs to know about definitions in other files, perhaps those that have never been opened or edited by the user.

A hacky solution would be, on the server side, to parse the URI of the workspace and just go load a bunch of files manually. But this seems like something that the LSP *should* support; perhaps I'm just missing where it's documented. (Also, it feels like I would be violating the spirit of the LSP design to do some covert ops like this behind the scenes, without communicating with the client.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for

**DidChangeWatchedFiles Notification**

See [Specification](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#workspace_didChangeWatchedFiles)

> The watched files notification is sent from the client to the server
> when the client detects changes to files and folders watched by the
> language client (note although the name suggest that only file events
> are sent it is about file system events which include folders as
> well). It is recommended that servers register for these file system
> events using the registration mechanism. In former implementations
> clients pushed file events without the server actively asking for it.

Basically the client is responsible of watching the files you require and sends a notification to the server each time something changes on them. At this point the server is capable to load them.

Answer (score 0):

DidChangeWatchedFiles Notification alone as suggested by another answer isn't enough as it only notifies you in the events of Create/Change/Delete.

Generally, most servers that need to do what you're describing accomplish this by reading all source files in the server when handling the [Initialize Request](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#initialize). So it's similar to what you're thinking. You can use `InitializeParams.workspaceFolders` to get the uri of the vscode workspace, and then just use your server language's file system apis to find your src files, read and do whatever initialization you need before returning a response to the client.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/blob/80fc538635beff0b36ade6f955cd7b552c5e3a9f/server/src/main/kotlin/org/javacs/kt/KotlinLanguageServer.kt#L118) from a kotlin language server.

After this, you can depend on [DidChangeWatchedFiles Notification](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#workspace_didChangeWatchedFiles) subsequently to handle changes after having already initialized all files.

This is better than implementing a file system watcher yourself in the server, which you could do, but is [not recommended by the LSP protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#workspace_didChangeWatchedFiles) for several reasons.

> Servers are allowed to run their own file system watching mechanism and not rely on clients to provide file system events. However this is not recommended due to the following reasons:
>
> - to our experience getting file system watching on disk right is challenging, especially if it needs to be supported across multiple OSes.
> - file system watching is not for free especially if the implementation uses some sort of polling and keeps a file system tree in memory to compare time stamps (as for example some node modules do)
> - a client usually starts more than one server. If every server runs its own file system watching it can become a CPU or memory problem.
> - in general there are more server than client implementations. So this problem is better solved on the client side.